# How do I get unique elements, in a case insensitive way in Ruby, and accounting for nil elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby, null, unique

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I get unique elements, in a case-insensitive way, from an array but accounting for nil elements?  I thougth this was the solution

```
data.map{|i| i || i.downcase}.uniq
```

but even after all my learning I'm still getting the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

when one of the elements in teh array is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says you want unique elements in a case-insensitive way. @Glyoko's answer does that.

If you want the elements all converted to lowercase (or uppercase) as well, that's different from what you asked.

`data.map(&:downcase).uniq` will work if all the elements of `data` are `downcase`able.  Otherwise, you'll get `NoMethodError`s.

You can eliminate the non-`downcase`able elements like this:

```
data.select{|item| item.respond_to? :downcase}.map(&:downcase).uniq
```

although if the only non-`downcase`able elements are `nil`s, you can eliminate those by simply `compact`ing the array first:

```
data.compact.map(&:downcase).uniq
```

Note that `ary.map(&:foo)` is shorthand for `ary.map {|item| item.foo}`.

Answer (score 2):

To do it your way, you just need to change the `||` to an `&&`. The `||` isn't doing anything when the element is nil.

Alternatively, you can use `&.` to make it a bit prettier. Also, you can shorten the whole thing by passing a block to `uniq`.

```
data.uniq { |datum| datum&.downcase }
```

*Unless* the results must also be downcased, in which case you do still need the map:

```
data.map { |datum| datum&.downcase }.uniq
```

Comment: This does avoid the exception I was getting but it doesn't return an array of lower-cased unique elements.  I still see the elements in their original form.

Comment: Yes it does? What test data are you using? It's true that this doesn't remove nils though, did you want that too? If you wanted to remove nils, you could just add `.compact` to the whole thing

Comment: No, this compares case-insensitively for the `uniq` process, but doesn't actually modify the elements.  `[ 'A', 'a' ].uniq(&:downcase)` may return `['A']` even though it turned that string into `'a'` for comparison purposes.

Comment: I used "data = [nil, "City", "Country"]".  Applying your function returns the same thing.

Comment: @natalia Why wouldn't it return the same thing?  Those are three distinct elements. A unique function won't change anything.

Comment: Oh, you didn't say you wanted the results to be downcased too. The way I read it I thought the case of the results didn't matter either. If that's the case then you do have to keep the map. `data.map { |datum| datum&.downcase }.uniq`

Comment: There is no need to show how you have edited your question. I suggest you remove the strike-throughs, which are just a distraction.